# How to run more tests by downloading logins in the database or excel webdriver selenium

Tags: sql, junit, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a list of n-logins that I would use to n times run the logon script to the site.
I have a simple script that logs :

```
    public class loginGoogle {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginGoogle() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=pl&service=mail&scc=1");
    assertEquals("Logowanie – Konta Google", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("account-chooser-add-account")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("LOGIN");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("PASSWORD");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_X.gbii")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
    }

    }
```

and I have a script that retrieves data from oracledb:

```
    package orclConn;

    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;


    public class orclConn {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;

    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mybase", "user",
                    "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
    System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }



    String sql ="select rownum,login from users";
    PreparedStatement preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
    ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
    while(result2.next()){
    System.out.println("Sheet " + result2.getString("rownum") + " login : " +  result2.getString("login"));
    }
    System.out.println("done");

    connection.close();

    }
 }
```

How does it connect to run the test example. 40 times? Login = password.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear for me to understand. Do you want to know the underlying layers of the connection between db and script or do u want to know how to execute the scripts 40 times after reading data from the database... please clarify

Comment: I have for example 40 logins downloaded from the database query by orclConn. I want to use them in turn to test the login where username = password (loginGoogle). How to combine the two scripts WebDriver so that it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using TestNG testing framework. In order to read from database and executing your test scripts you are required to use Data providers. Please refer to the following tutorial:

[TestNG Parameters & Data Provider](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/)

Also you can use the following information to read data from a database and save it in a hashmap to later feed it back to the data-provider.

```
 Map<String, String> IDMap = new HashMap<String, String>();             //Initializing a Map

 while(result2.next()){
    System.out.println("Sheet " + result2.getString("rownum") + " login : " +  result2.getString("login"));
    IDMap.put(result2.getString("login"), result2.getString("login"));  //Saving the database information in a Map
}
```